# Configuration of wireless adapter

Tags: 14.04, wireless, adapter

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and have tried to configure the adapter which is a Linksys WUSB6300, but seem to have no response.
I have tried using the startup CD to activate the adapter but seem to get only errors.

Answer (score 0):

try to go in

System , All Settings-> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers

and check if there is any driver available , 
if it is the case  , check its case and apply change ,

Comment: There is nothing that comes up in the Additional Drivers

Comment: Have you tried to install **linux-firmware-nonfree**?